# AngularJS ng-repeat slightly slow updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm attempting to create a line numbering system for a `textarea` element using Angular's `ng-repeat` directive. Essentially, using the `ng-keyup` event, I'm calling a function `updateLineNumbers()` that calculates the total amount of lines in the `textarea` and adds to an array of line numbers attached to the `$scope` if needed.

```
angular.module('editorApp')
.controller('LineNumberController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.lines = [1];
    $scope.updateLineNumber = function(){
        var text = $("#editor").val();   
        var lines = text.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
        var count = lines.length;
        console.log(count);
        if(count > $scope.lines.length){
            console.log("adding line...");
            var len = $scope.lines.length;
            var linesToAdd = count - len;
            console.log("lines to add: " + linesToAdd);
            for(var i = 0; i < linesToAdd; i++){
                console.log('adding line number: ' + (i + $scope.lines[len - 1] + 1));
                $scope.lines.push(i + $scope.lines[len - 1] + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

The console log statements are just for debugging purposes btw. This works fine, and everything displays how i want it, however I notice its just slightly slow. The new line number appears just a moment behind the cursor making it to the next line. I know its picky, but this bothers me and I was wondering if there was a solution for this in Angular, or if I should just use JQuery.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="main-editor" ng-controller="LineNumberController">
      <div class="line-numbers">
        <div ng-repeat="line in lines" id="line{{ $index + 1 }}">{{ $index + 1 }}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-container">
        <textarea name="editor" id="editor" cols="30" rows="10" ng-keyup="updateLineNumber()"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the plunkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/0POJTx0p4rtfwOAaNRPb?p=preview

Comment: Create a demo we can fork and test this. Seems like the line counter code could be streamlined quite a bit

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. The code I provided should be enough, I can add more angular code to show the entire controller definition.

Comment: seems to work reasonably well here http://plnkr.co/edit/b5fEwUGCzb5i7OBUZXW0?p=preview . Missing logic though when user removes rows

Comment: yes the delete code is missing because i didn't implement it yet. I'm waiting to see what the best way to do the line numbers, because its still a little slow for my liking.

Comment: I edited the plunkr to include the css code

Comment: need to fork and provide link then. Update question with that link

Comment: its updated with the plunkr link

Comment: Using `ng-keydown` makes it faster for me, although it does ignore the first line. Add a few lines and you'll see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler approach using a watch on `ng-model`

The important part is using `ng-trim="false"` otherwise `ng-model` will trim breaks after last character

```
  var lineCount = 1;
  $scope.$watch('model.editor', function(nV, oV) {
    if (!nV) {
      $scope.lines = [1];    
    } else {
      var lines = nV.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
      // create new array if number of lines changed
      if (lines.length !== lineCount) {
        $scope.lines = lines.map(function(_, i) {
          return i + 1
        });
        lineCount = lines.length;
      }
    }
  });
```

View

```
  <div class="line-numbers">
    <div ng-repeat="line in lines" id="line{{ $index + 1 }}">{{ line }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="editor-container">
    <textarea name="editor" id="editor" cols="30" rows="10" ng-model="model.editor" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
  </div>
```

Note this works also while removing data.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/cKDdSbbbbbTcZ4qSylhI?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Great solution! Strange bug however, for some reason when I implemented it in my own code the line numbers start at 1, and skip 2, then continue on fine from 3 to infinity.

Comment: you are probably still using `$index` in view, my array creates actual numbers and uses `line` in view

Comment: I switched it over to {{ line }} and it still skips 2. The line numbers are always one behind the cursor, but the correct line number (skipping 2).

Comment: is it doing it in my demo also? I tried mine in chrome and firefox

Comment: I'm soo stupid! I some css that was hiding line 2 specifically when I was testing something else out and I forgot to take that code out. (facepalm). Everything works fine now!

Comment: I did play a lot with using key events and I think that angular must throttle them a little bit or something. Not sure why it was a bit slower